# Android Studio Restore Logcat View

Tags: android, android-studio

Just just installed AS and my LogCat view is now in separate window (that is bad).
Is there any way to put it back to tab as it as I think default.

[image]

[image]

Comment: window -> restore layout should do it

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't help

Comment: did you try to drag it where it was before ?

Comment: Ohh)) Yes now it works it is really hard to drag it, really

Comment: cool, I am glad you fixed it :D